# JPA: Sometimes a merge is missed

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a Job entity with a primary key (ID). 
I persist it to get the id set.
Then I update a field (ImgWorkName) that needs the ID.

*Most of the time* (like 999 out of 1000 times) everything works file. 
But *sometimes* (like 1 out of 1000 times) the updated field haven't been set when I do a subsequent query in JPA!
The field is in the database (so if I restart the application I always see the updated field)

I am an experienced programmer. 
I have been struggling with this problem for more than a year now, so I'd be really happy for some help!

The problem started to show up 3-4 years ago, but very seldom, and then slowly this error popped up more and more often so now it happens almost every day.

A month ago I upgraded the server from Ubuntu 12 to Ubuntu 16 - no difference.

A month ago I upgraded from Java 6 to Java 8 - no difference.

Then I upgraded the 7 years old JPA libraries to JPA 2.1 and to the newest Tomcat 7 - no difference.

During the years the database has been growing larger and larger. There are now around 1 million rows in the MySQL Job table, but the query only returns around 600 rows.
It seems like a JPA bug to me, but I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

Below are the relevant code snippets. Thanks in advance!

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
public class Job implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "imgOrgName", length = 300)
  private String imgOrgName;

  @Column(name = "imgWorkName", length = 100)
  private String imgWorkName;

  @Column(name = "created")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date created;

  @Column(name = "todoFileSize")
  private Integer todoFileSize;

  // more fields, getters and setters
}




public class FF {

  public EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(emfNavn);

  public EntityManager emq = emf.createEntityManager();

  // Bad workaround
  private LinkedHashMap<Integer, Job> jobIdTilJobWorkaround = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Job>();


  private void scanCustomerTodoDir() {

        EntityManager emEnqueueJobs = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
          // Add all files as jobs (we dont know the new jobids yet)
          emEnqueueJobs.getTransaction().begin();
          ArrayList<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();

          for (Path f : subfiles) {

            Job j = new Job();
            j.file_tmp = f;
            j.setTodoFileSize((int) f.toFile().length());
            j.setCreated(new Date());
            j.setUser(user);
            j.setService(service);
            j.setImgOrgName(imgOrgName);
            j.setState("QUEUED");
            jobs.add(j);
            emEnqueueJobs.persist(j);
          }

          // commit to get all jobids
          emEnqueueJobs.getTransaction().commit();


          for (Job j : jobs) {
            emEnqueueJobs.getTransaction().begin();
            // Use the Job ID to decide file name
            File fn = new File("/some/path/and/stuff_"+j.getId()); 
            j.setImgWorkName(fn.getName());     // This update gets lost!    
            emEnqueueJobs.merge(j);

            emEnqueueJobs.getTransaction().commit();

            jobIdTilJobWorkaround.put(j.getId(), j);  // BAD workaround for unfinishedJobsq missing the ImgWorkName in the merge!    
          }
        } finally {
          emEnqueueJobs.close();
        }
  }

  public Query unfinishedJobsq = emq.createNativeQuery("select * from ff.job WHERE state = 'QUEUED' OR state = 'GROUPWAIT' ORDER BY id DESC", Job.class);

  private void scanServiceproviderDoneDir() {
    List<Job> unfinishedJobs = unfinishedJobsq.getResultList();
    for (Job j : unfinishedJobs) try {

      if (j.getImgWorkName() == null) { // error! This happens sometimes!
        Job j2 = jobIdTilJobWorkaround.get(j.getId());
        // BAD workaround code for broken JPA (missing the ImgWorkName) here
        j = j2;
      }

      if (...) {   // The commit below always works/merges
        EntityManager emJobState = emf.createEntityManager();
        emJobState.getTransaction().begin();
        j.setState("DONE");
        long str = doneFile.length();
        j.setDoneFileSize((int) str);
        j.setDone(new Date());
        emJobState.merge(j);
        emJobState.getTransaction().commit();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ffprod" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>ff.db.User</class>
    <class>ff.db.Job</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.native-sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/ff"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="ff"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to wrap the entire `scanCustomerTodoDir ` code in a single transaction? You don't need to commit the transaction to get the ids, a `flush` would be enough

Comment: EclipseLink uses a persistence unit cache by default, which is shared across entity managers; it acts as a second-level cache for the local entity manager caches. It's possible you're getting stale entries in there. Try setting `<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>` in your persistence-unit XML and see what happens. Other than that, search for "MySQL stale data"; seems to be quite a few hits for similar behavior. Example: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21446

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023935/new-entitymanager-sometimes-getting-stale-data-from-mysql

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I think I have the right pointers now, googling 'JPA MySQL stale data'. I suspect I am running in REPEATABLE-READ mode and that the error will probably go away if I change to READ COMMITTED.

Comment: I don't know how changing from REPEATABLE-READ mode to READ committed is going to change anything - unless you know exactly what is causing your issue, it is a shot in the dark, and the difference  between these two modes seems it is unlikely the case.  As mentioned the first time, your persist is a separate transaction from the update, so if your read operation is a separate thread, it could pick up the new instances but not the updates.  Putting them in one transaction will ensure a separate operation will get all or none.

Comment: You are using emq for your native query while using a different/new Em for everything else.  Since EntityManagers have their own cache meant to mirror a transaction, you might want to check that you aren't holding onto this EntityManager for long periods, or are clearing it at appropriate intervals.  everything read through it remains cached, and queries, even native queries, will return the cached/managed instances of entities.  You need to run special query hints if you need to force refreshes.